# Perpendicular straight lines given with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Show that $Re(az+b)=0$ and $Re(cz+d)=0$ are perpendicular iff $Re(a\bar{c})=0$

My problem is I do not know what perpendicularity of these two lines imply.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: For bar on top, type \bar{c} in math mode. Output: $\bar{c}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$ax+b$ and $cx+d$ are perpendicular if and only if $c=-\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do we get this fact tho?

Comment: Two lines are perpendicular if and only if the two vector direction are perpendicular. What is the vectori direction of a line of equation $y=ax+b$ ? What can you conclude ?

Comment: I am still confused

Comment: the line $y=ax+b$ can be parametrize as $\gamma (t)=(t,at+b)=(1,a)t+(1,b)$ and $y=cx+d$ as $\delta(t)=(1,c)t+(1,d)$. You have that $\gamma (t)\perp \delta(t)$ if and only if $(1,a)\perp (1,b)$, i.e. $0=\langle (1,a),(1,c)\rangle=1+ac\implies a=-\frac{1}{c}$. Is it fine ?

Comment: yes it is fine know thanks a lot